# On a generalized question regarding Null space $(T) \cap$ Range $T$ = $\{0\}$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation over an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $Rank (T)\leq Rank (T^n)$. Can we conclude that Null space $(T) \cap$ Range $T$ = $\{0\}$?

> Clearly, $Rank (T) = Rank (T^n)$ and we can also conclude $null (T) = null (T^n)$. Letting $v \in range (T) \cap null (T)$, there exists $w$ in $V$ such that $T(w) = v$ and also $Tv = 0$. $v \in null(T) = null (T^n)$. If we can conclude that $T^{n-1} v = 0$, then $T^n (w) = 0 \implies w \in null(T) \implies v = T(w) = 0$.Therefore we need to confirm $T^{n-1} v = 0$. Can we do so? Since null space must contain zero vector, I think we can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier and more conceptual way is the following:

$\text{rank}(T)=\text{rank}(T^2)$ implies that their range have the same dimension. Let $W=T(V)$ be the range of $T$. But clearly, $T^2(V) = T(W)$, and so since $\text{dim}(W)=\text{dim}(T(W))$ by assumption, we must have that $T$ is injective on $W$, i.e. $\text{null}(T)\cap W=\emptyset$.